# Formatting parameter as string in javascript function from .NET

Tags: javascript, c#

My problem is how to properly format string in javascript function parameter list. Function call is created on the server, problem is with string single apostrophes.

Code (.NET, C#) (I want only element.cMEST_CDO2 in single quotes):

```
@"ng-click='DeleteElementFromSession(" + element.iMERC_KEY + "," + element.iACCO_KEY + 
@",'" + element.cMEST_CDO2 + @"');'></i></div>";
```

This code is on the client visible like this (it throws error):

[image]

I would like to be like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

What I've found out with help from Kevin is, that anything that is being rendered wiht HTML should be HTML encoded.

My solution - I've made whole string instead of single params and html encoded whole string:

```
string paramList = $"{element.iMERC_KEY},{element.iACCO_KEY},'{element.cMEST_CDO2}', $event";
paramList = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(paramList);
```

And then insert this string into parameter list:

```
 @"ng-click='DeleteElementFromSession(" + paramList + ");'></i></div>";
```

Comment: It should work as expected. Are you sure you copied the right code?

Comment: `@"ng-click='DeleteElementFromSession(" + element.iMERC_KEY + "," + element.iACCO_KEY + 
@",'"` << here it ends and after that you do `+ element.cMEST_CDO2 + @"');'></i></div>";` just noticed that this could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @KevinKloet - I agree with you. Perhaps you have idea how to insert first apostrophe?

Comment: something like this should work: 

`@"ng-click='DeleteElementFromSession(" + element.iMERC_KEY + "," + element.iACCO_KEY + 
@"," + element.cMEST_CDO2 + @");'></i></div>";`

Comment: @KevinKloet - this gives me last parameter without single quotes, which throws error in javascript. Only numbers are allowed without single quotes.

Comment: this should add the single quotes to it: `@"ng-click='DeleteElementFromSession(" + element.iMERC_KEY + "," + element.iACCO_KEY + 
@",'+'" + element.cMEST_CDO2 + @"'+');'></i></div>'";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found out with help from [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606899/formatting-parameter-as-string-in-javascript-function-from-net#comment68448842_40606899) is, that anything that is being rendered wiht HTML should be HTML encoded.

My solution - I've made whole string instead of single params and html encoded whole string:

```
string paramList = $"{element.iMERC_KEY},{element.iACCO_KEY},'{element.cMEST_CDO2}', $event";
paramList = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(paramList);
```

And then insert this string into parameter list:

```
 @"ng-click='DeleteElementFromSession(" + paramList + ");'></i></div>";
```